# Trigger onclick event of an anchor tag on document onload

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have built a custom plugin in Wordpress. Its basically a Customer Feedback form which pops up when you are at the home page.

Presently when I install this plugin, it creates a anchor link in the footer. This was just for testing purposes.

When I click on the anchor link that is generated in the footer, it opens up my customer feedback in a custom pop-up that I created using Jquery and CSS.

But I want to load the pop-up when my page is loaded and not clicking on anchor link.

For that I used jQuery trigger function to call the Click event of that anchor on document load.

```
But its not working. Here is my code below :

**jQuery code**

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('hi');
    jQuery('a.static_button').trigger('click');

    function alert_popup(){
        alert('yo yo yo .....you good to go.!!!');
    }

    jQuery('a.static_button').click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });
});
```

Code from my **plugin file**

```
<?php
function myscript(){
  wp_enqueue_script('light');
  wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet');
?>
    <a href="#" id="go-to-top" onclick="javascript:alert_popup();"  class="static_button topopup">Click here</a>
    <!-- PopUp Div goes here -->
     <div class="loader"></div>
      <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
      <div id="toPopup">
          <div class="close">X</div>
              <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
                <div class="contact_form">
                    <form>
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[cust]');?>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
      <!-- PopUp Div ends here -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try having the listener before the trigger?

Comment: I didn't feel the need to do so, as I checked putting this in the anchor tag `onclick="javascript:alert('hii');"` and calling it on document load by using this  `jQuery('a.static_button').trigger('click');` it showed me a popup saying "hi" @Secret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the example here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ as a reference

Your code should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('hi');

    function alert_popup(){
        alert('yo yo yo .....you good to go.!!!');
    }

    jQuery('a.static_button').click(function() {
            loading(); // loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup(); // function show popup
            }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;
    });

    jQuery('a.static_button').trigger('click'); <----- after

});
```

A sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56JHm/).

Comment: @roskStar Yes I tried even this, but it didn't work.

Comment: BTW is your `alert_popup()` being called?

Comment: To @all it worked by placing the trigger call at the end of all functions that are in my javascript file. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Try this, I tested it this time and it will work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        alert('yo yo yo .....you good to go.!!!'); 
    });
    $('#test').trigger('click');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

   <a href="#" id="test">Click here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

You have some typos in your code.

Comment: It worked by placing the trigger call right at the end of all functions. Pheww.!!! Thank you for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

see you are calling **loadPopup()** on click event of  ***anchor*** tag..then why don't you call **loadPopup()** function directly on page load?

Comment: that what I'm trying to do, as you can read my question correctly. Onload is not working.

Comment: you can use this..                          http://geektastical.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-pop-up-wordpress-email-contact-form/                                                    live example...                                                           http://www.realpropmart.com/